# Can't pass 403 forbidden error code using Spring Security

Tags: spring, spring-boot, authentication, spring-security, spring-jdbc

I'm trying to set up a basic auth server with cookie sessions. I'll be communicating from a client to this service in Java and Spring. Now, the thing is I can't pass basic login endpoint, but I get returned a cookie set 'SESSION' but with a 403 Forbidden code with path "/login". The cookie data is stored in my Postgres database correctly (as I'm using JDBC authentication strategy). I don't understand how to proced since I can't log/debug these functions internally to see what's happening.

The security config:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
    @Bean
    @Override
    public UserDetailsService userDetailsServiceBean() throws Exception {
        return super.userDetailsServiceBean();
    }

    @Bean
    @Override
    public AuthenticationManager authenticationManagerBean() throws Exception {
        return super.authenticationManagerBean();
    }

    @Autowired
    private DataSource dataSource;

    @Bean
    public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth)
        throws Exception {
        auth
            .jdbcAuthentication()
            .dataSource(dataSource)
            .passwordEncoder(passwordEncoder())
            .usersByUsernameQuery("""
                    SELECT username, password, enabled
                    FROM users
                    WHERE username=?
                """)
            .authoritiesByUsernameQuery("""
                    SELECT u.username, a.authority
                    FROM users u, authorities a
                    WHERE u.username=? AND a.username=u.username
                """)
        ;
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
            .cors().and().csrf().disable()
            .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/auth/**").permitAll()
                .antMatchers("/users/**").authenticated()
            .and()
                .sessionManagement()
                .sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.IF_REQUIRED)
            ;

    }

}
```

AuthController:

```
@RequestMapping("/auth")
@RestController
@RequiredArgsConstructor
@Slf4j
public class AuthController {
    private final UserRepository userRepository;
    private final UserService userService;

    private final UserDetailsService userDetailsService;
    private final AuthenticationManager authenticationManager;

    @PostMapping("/login")
    ResponseEntity login(@RequestBody LoginRequest request) {
        var userDetails = userDetailsService.loadUserByUsername(request.getUsername());
        var token = new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(
            userDetails,
            userDetails.getPassword(),
            userDetails.getAuthorities()
        );

        authenticationManager.authenticate(token);
        if (token.isAuthenticated()) {
            SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(token);
        }

        return ResponseEntity.ok("Logged");
    }

    @Data
    private static class LoginRequest {
        private Long id;
        private String username, password;
    }

}
```

Before 'authenticationManager.authenticate(token)' I can log the authorities/roles of userService correctly. Then, using token.isAuthenticated, when trying to log anything inside if or else, or past that block, is just ignored. So I guess there's something happening inside these functions I can't debug. Any help is appreciated. Thank you.
Note that I won't be using templates, just external call requests.

Comment: Adding "and().httpBasic()"  made 403 error stop happening, but now I have a 401 error, yet cookie is still stored on Postgres and set on client.

Comment: Why havnt you just looked in the debug logs?

Comment: No error is being logged. Wrapping 'authentiticationManager.authenticate(token)' in try-catch block says 401 error is caused by a BadCredentials error. Any idea? I don't think credentials are wrong.

Comment: All errors are logged, what you are looking at is probably the INFO logs. You should learn how to enable DEBUG logs and look at them before asking here.

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I got what was causing the obvious BadCredentials exception, but I'll write the steps in order to make the snippet code above functional/correct:

1. Add chain method ".and()" followed by ".httpBasic()".
   This is not yet done - it now allows correctly authentication with username/password, but in the snippet code there was a mistake.
2. While creating 'token' variable, you have to pass request password input. I noticed just because I didn't use the incoming password anywhere and I said: well, It's obvious I need to compare to it actually.
   Now it works okay. I hope this helps a confused mind trying to following a 403/401 error response while doing Spring Security Authentication.

Changed:

```
new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(
            userDetails,
            request.getPassword(),
            userDetails.getAuthorities()
);
```